# Sorting a NSFetchRequest based on entity class

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

I am using CoreData and have two sub-entities with a common abstract super-entity, let's call them

```
SuperEntity,
FirstSubEntity and
SecondSubEntity
```

All three entities have their own subclass of `NSManagedObject` or `SuperEntity`.

I'm using a `NSFetchRequest` to fetch all objects of type `SuperEntity`, meaning I will get a set of all `FirstSubEntities` and `SecondSubEntities` all jumbled together. I want to sort this set based on the entity class, like this.

- `<FirstSubEntity id=X>`
- `<FirstSubEntity id=X>`
- `<FirstSubEntity id=X>`
- ...
- `<SecondSubEntity id=X>`
- `<SecondSubEntity id=X>`
- ...

I'm trying to set an `NSSortDescriptor` with key `class`:

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"class" ascending:YES]
```

Unfortunately it throws an exception

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath class not found in entity <NSSQLEntity SuperEntity id=X>'
```

Curiously, if I instead use an `NSFetchedResultsController` I'm able to set the sectionName to `class` like this

```
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext
                                      sectionNameKeyPath:@"class"
                                                acheName:nil];
```

Which works fine. Any ideas on how to manage this with `NSSortDescriptors`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That works in the `sectionNameKeyPath` because the `sectionNameKeyPath` is resolved after the objects are loaded into memory.  The `NSFetchRequest` and its sort descriptors are done at the SQLite level which the key `class` is meaningless.

Further, at the SQL level, your two entities are really in the same table so there is no way to differentiate and therefore sort them at that point.

Your only solution is to sort them in memory, not in the fetch directly.  You can use a `NSSortDescriptor` against the returned array from a normal fetch request and in that case I would use `entity.name` instead of `class`.

Comment: ‘It no longer works for iOS 10: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath entity.name not found in entity <NSSQLEntity [EntityName] id=1>’'

Markus, is it still possible to sort results by entity name? Do you have a solution?